# Line segments on a geoboard

Tags: geometry, manipulatives

To make a polygon on a traditional geoboard, one usually stretches a rubber band around the vertices. No problem there.

When making a simple line segment, however, a rubber band is typically stretched between the two end points. This creates a “segment” that looks like two closely spaced parallel lines.

**Is there a way to make an actual line segment on a geoboard?**

I looked for loop-less rubber bands with little holes on each end to fit over the pegs, but I had no luck.

Computer-based/virtual geoboards tend not have this problem, and seeing these made me wonder how it could be done on physical boards.

Comment: Couldn't you loop the rubber band over one end, and twist it before looping it over the other end so that the parallel lines become one?

Comment: @Nathan Nice. Please submit this idea as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @EJ Mak, I've posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One practical way to do this might be to loop the rubber band over one end, and to then twist it before looping it over the other end. In this way the parallel lines combine to become one.

This would not work well with "fat" rubber bands, but should be fine with regular rubber bands.

Answer (score 2):

You could cut open the rubber bands and tie loops/knots at the ends. Downside of course is that you'd have to manually tie the knots for however many you need.

EDIT: It occurs to me that it's possible to tie knots without cutting them in half, then just make sure the rubber band go on one side of the pegs. Probably eaiser this way, too.

Comment: Maybe the kids could tie the knots.  Preparing the rubber bands might help them understand why it's needed.